# VBScript with SeleniumBasic closes the browser automatically

Tags: vbscript

Here's the basic script I am running - using SeleniumBasic. It opens chrome but closes as well immediately. I dont see any error in logs. (Running it in VS code)

```
Class Script
    Dim driver
    Sub Class_Initialize
        Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
        driver.Get "http://www.google.com"
    End Sub
End Class

Set s = New Script
```

Comment: When a COM object goes out of scope it closes.

Comment: any idea, how can i avoid that ?

Comment: Take a reference to it if doing COM. Program like MS Word take a COM reference to themselves else they close as soon as they finish starting if the user starts it and DON't do that if a program starts it..

Comment: Your question lacks context for a better answer.

Comment: I am trying to automate chrome to open website for testing using SeleniumBasic. Being new to this found above code on google and tried to run it. I was expecting browser to remain open once script is executed as there is no quit/close in script.

How to make above script to keep browser open after script execution ?

Comment: Execute the file so it opens like a user would and use `GetObject` on it. You need to read help on `GetObject` as it is overloaded. `GetObject(Filename)` switches to filename or opens if not already open returning a document object. `GetObject(,"Internet.Explorer")` note `,` we are setting the SECOND parameter - Switches to an already running application only returning an Application Object. The third that I not seen anyone do is `GetObject(FileName, Application.Name)` open doc in app. These are COM rules, note office often ignore some of them because users don't always like it.

Comment: Some other ignored rules COM Servers open documents invisible unless set to visible in code.